# mysql Подгрузка данные без повторений

Tags: mysql

есть запрос вида

```
SELECT user_id FROM user
WHERE
    user_active = 1
ORDER BY user_reg_date DESC LIMIT 0,2

//результат 
// user_id
//    3
//    6
```

есть кнопка подгрузки, где изменяется offset (то есть в следующий запрос будет `LIMIT 2,2`)

бывает, что перед запросом появляется еще user который вставляется где-то между (или изменяется уже созданный-неактивный на другую дату, допустим) и при нажатии на подгрузить еще появляется уже подруженный ранее... как от такого избавится, какой запрос должен быть или что не так?

пример:

```
// уже загрузил
// user_id
//    3
//    6  - пауза, потом подрузить еще...
//    6  - вот этот не должен загружатся, должно начать с 4 и далее, получется дублируется
//    4 - должно быть 4, 7 - например
```

Comment: Вопрос: зачем? Чем это мешает?

Comment: Был бы у вас Oracle, я бы предложил использовать flashback запросы, т.е. запросы показывающие данные, как они были на определенный момент времени. Но MySQL так не умеет и если это действительно надо, единственный путь - помнить полное состояние таблицы на момент выбора первой страницы для данного пользователя. Но это слишком дорого. Так что правильный ответ - забейте, в 99% систем пагинация работает именно так, как у вас сейчас.

Comment: А если `user_reg_date` это дата регистрации пользователя - то вообще не ясно как она может меняться. А если она только у новых, то помните максимальную дату, которая была в таблице на момент начала пагинации для пользователя и получайте количество новых пользователей перед выполнением запроса и корректируйте limit

Comment: @Mike спасибо за отзыв, `data` может быть не только новой, то для примера, вообщем я понял, что простого решения нету, хотел переубедится...

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, поможет добавление в WHERE следующей инструкции

```
AND user_id NOT IN (3, 6)
```

, где 3, 6 кортеж уже отобажённых user_id

Comment: остается придумать, где хранить отображенные, особенно если в таблице тысячи записей и что делать, если пользователь решил пропустить пару страниц, стразу после первой полез на 4ю

Comment: ну по сути это вариант, если сохранять последние 5-10 `user_id` последнего запроса и использовать их как `NOT IN`, и тогда повторения по сути не должно быть...